# Checking brand new hydraulic lifters

Tags: untagged

Recently, I bought a complete set of OEM hydraulic lifters. They are all nice and shiny.
They are all inside small plastic bottles and there is some oil inside each bottle.
I looked inside all the lifters and they were all fine except for one of them.
Please have a look at the following pictures:

[image]
[image]

All lifters are similar to picture B. There is clean oil inside.
However, there are some tiny particles inside one of them (picture A). It looks as if the oil has been dried or something. They can be easily removed by hand.

Now my question is:
What are they and what should I do? I'm worried about this one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the lifter out of the container. Spray it down liberally, inside/out with brake or carb cleaner. If the lifter will collapse at all, squish it and see if you can get anything out of the inside of it. If not, use the brake/carb cleaner to spray into the oil ports the best you can to clean it out. Once you get it cleaned to the point where you can't get any more of whatever it is out of it, then soak the lifter in fresh oil (whatever you're going to use for first start) for several hours (or longer). The idea with the soaking is to displace anything else in the lifter with the oil which might be present and to have the lifter fully lubed prior to putting them into place for reassembly.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I also wanted to clean it with carb cleaner. I was worried about this one being fake and all others being original. Is it possible? How can I test the other ones? How should they feel when I press them by hand?

Comment: I doubt it's fake. Probably just some contaminates in with the protective oil.